# volume of cone,cylinder, hemisphere

Tags: geometry, volume

[image: volume of cone,cylinder,hemisphere]

So I find volume of hemisphere: $\frac{2}{3}\pi r^3$

volume of cylinder is $\pi r^2h$

volume of cone is $\frac{1}{3}r^2\pi h$

now how to proceed to solve, calculate $h$(height), and use the ratio?
I can find hemisphere's volume using the formula but then how to proceed?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Find the volume of the hemisphere. Then use the given ratios to find the other volumes. There is no need to find the heights of cylinder and cone (which are not the same).